# How to read the shape of all images and display them, present in a dataset folder through google colab?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning

I am trying to train my image dataset on google colab. I have the dataset folder present in colab. When trying to read the images from the directory in colab, I am just able to read the file name of all the images. However, if I try extracting the shape of the images in an array, it gives different errors with different approaches. I have tried using **os** library and **PIL.Image** and even **pickle**, but I am still not able to sort or even guess what could be the issue. 
The errors which I am getting are:

> 1) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
>   2) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'seek'

Both when using `os.walk(path)` function in a for loop and picking up the files from the resultant list of all files present in the path.

> 3) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '7119-220.jpg'

This seems weird as it is looking out specifically for the same file each time I run the code. By using try and except for this `FileNotFoundError` I don't get any output.

**Question:** What's the mistake that I am not getting?

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

imagesPath = 'Neural_Net-for-Concrete-Crack-Detection/Wall_crack_dataset/W/CW'

target_names = [item for item in os.listdir(imagesPath)
                if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(imagesPath, item))]
number_train_samples = sum([len(files) for _, _, files in os.walk(imagesPath)])  

image = np.zeros((256, 256), dtype=int)

total_number_samples = number_train_samples

print('Training a CNN Multi-Classifier Model ......')
print(' - # of trained samples: ', number_train_samples, 
       '\n - total # of samples: ', total_number_samples)
```

This piece works for just counting the number of image files.

```
from PIL import Image
import os
i=0
image = np.zeros((256, 256), dtype='uint8')

imagesPath = 'Neural_Net-for-Concrete-Crack-Detection/Wall_crack_dataset/W/CW'

for _, _, files in os.walk(imagesPath):
  for file in files:
    image = Image.open(file)
```

This code works better if I specify a particular image file in the directory to be plotted, but not for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`os.walk(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) yields a 3-tuple `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`. Therefore, you should try to open `os.path.join(dirpath, file)` instead of `file`:

```py
from PIL import Image
import os
i=0
image = np.zeros((256, 256), dtype='uint8')

imagesPath = 'Neural_Net-for-Concrete-Crack-Detection/Wall_crack_dataset/W/CW'

for dirpath, _, files in os.walk(imagesPath):  # <--
  for file in files:
    image = Image.open(os.path.join(dirpath, file))  # <--
```

If you need a `dataset` with shape `(n_samples, channels, height, width)` and you want to stick to `PIL.Image`, you can do this:

```py
dataset_dir = "[DATASET_DIR]"
dataset = np.asarray([
    np.asarray(  # convert from PIL.Image to np.array
        Image.open(os.path.join(dirpath, img_fname))  # open image
    ).transpose((2,0,1))  # change from (H,W,C) to (C,H,W)
    for dirpath, _, fnames in os.walk(dataset_dir)  # scan the `dataset_dir`
    for img_fname in fnames  # for each file in `dataset_dir`
])
```

Pay attention that it requires all images to have the same `shape`.

Comment: I am getting the files using this approach, but still not able to store the image shape and array. I tried using img_to_array from keras.preprocessing.image library. All I want is store the image as an array in dataset array defined as:  
dataset = np.ndarray(shape=(len(train_files), channels, image_height, image_width),
                     dtype=np.float32)

Comment: @rajkumaryadav your original question is missing these infos. I updated my answer with a code that gives you a dataset the way you want without using keras, and I'd recommend you to open another question if you have a problem with keras. If you find my answer helpful, consider upvoting. If you open a follow-up question, you can paste the link here and I may take a look at it.